# Reinstantiate custom class from string

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

whats the best way to re-instantiate a class from a persisted datastructure?

currently when storing I `JSON.stringify()` it then parse that string when re instantiating like so

```
 module.exports = class Player {
  constructor(str, isExistingInstance=false, rsn) {
    if(isExistingInstance) {
      try {
        parsedObject = JSON.parse(str)
        this.rsn = parsedObject.rsn 
        this.skills = parsedObject.skills
        this.kc = parsedObject.kc
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error instantiating object from exisiting instance. Expected JSON.stringify'd version of Player, Received: ", str)
      }
  } else {
    if(!rsn) throw new Error("Expected type of string for rsn, received: ", typeof(rsn));
  }
}
```

i'm not a fan of this method because you have to supply `str` even when its not an existing instance. Does anyone have any suggestions on how it could be improved?

My current thought is "builder" functions similar to this:

```
function buildNewPlayer(rsn) {
  new Player(null, false, rsn);
}

function buildExistingPlayer(str, rsn) {
  new Player(str, true, ""); 
}
```

This method just seems messy or dirty, I feel like there must be a cleaner way to handle the re-instantiation.

Comment: Have a static `fromJSON` method on the class. Then you can do `const player = Player.fromJSON(str)`. That method can do all the parsing an setting of properties as necessary.

Comment: ooh. that does sound cleaner. then re-create with something like `const existingPlayer = new Player().fromJSON(str)`?

Comment: @FelixKling I like your suggestion the best. using a static method seems to me to be the cleanest method. If you post an answer I will accept it! :)

Answer (score 0):

the constructor should be used for creating the instance, move the parsing and building to a method and call it after instantiating the class :

```js
class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.rsn = null;
    this.skills = null;
    this.kc = null;
  }

  build(str, rsn) {
    if (rsn) {
      try {
        const parsedObject = JSON.parse(str);
        this.rsn = parsedObject.rsn;
        this.skills = parsedObject.skills;
        this.kc = parsedObject.kc;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(
          "Error instantiating object from exisiting instance. Expected JSON.stringify'd version of Player, Received: ",
          str
        );
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Expected type of string for rsn, received: ", typeof rsn);
    }
  }
}

const str = '{"rsn": 123, "skills" : "a lot", "kc": "kc"}';

const playerOne = new Player();
playerOne.build(str, 123);

console.log(playerOne.skills);
```